# Strange forward declaration error reported by llvm-gcc-4.2

Tags: gcc, declaration, forward, libx265

When I use llvm-gcc-4.2 within Xcode4.6.3 to compile 'x265' sources, it reported a strange error:
./source/encoder/reference.h:38:error: forward declaration of 'class x265::MotionReference'.However, the class declaration of x265::MotionReference is complete in reference.h:

```
#ifndef X265_REFERENCE_H
#define X265_REFERENCE_H

#include "primitives.h"
#include "picyuv.h"
#include "lowres.h"
#include "mv.h"

namespace X265_NS {
// private x265 namespace

struct WeightParam;

class MotionReference : public ReferencePlanes
{
public:

    MotionReference();
    ~MotionReference();
    int  init(PicYuv*, WeightParam* wp, const x265_param& p);
    void applyWeight(int rows, int numRows);

    pixel*  weightBuffer[3];
    int     numInterpPlanes;
    int     numWeightedRows;

protected:

    MotionReference& operator =(const MotionReference&);
};
}
```

and it's parent class is defined in header file 'lowres.h':

```
#ifndef X265_LOWRES_H
#define X265_LOWRES_H

#include "primitives.h"
#include "common.h"
#include "picyuv.h"
#include "mv.h"

namespace X265_NS {
// private namespace

struct ReferencePlanes
{
    ReferencePlanes() { memset(this, 0, sizeof(ReferencePlanes)); }

    pixel*   fpelPlane[3];
    pixel*   lowresPlane[4];
    PicYuv*  reconPic;

    bool     isWeighted;
    bool     isLowres;

    intptr_t lumaStride;
    intptr_t chromaStride;

    struct {
        int      weight;
        int      offset;
        int      shift;
        int      round;
    } w[3];

    pixel* getLumaAddr(uint32_t ctuAddr, uint32_t absPartIdx) { return fpelPlane[0] + reconPic->m_cuOffsetY[ctuAddr] + reconPic->m_buOffsetY[absPartIdx]; }
    pixel* getCbAddr(uint32_t ctuAddr, uint32_t absPartIdx)   { return fpelPlane[1] + reconPic->m_cuOffsetC[ctuAddr] + reconPic->m_buOffsetC[absPartIdx]; }
    pixel* getCrAddr(uint32_t ctuAddr, uint32_t absPartIdx)   { return fpelPlane[2] + reconPic->m_cuOffsetC[ctuAddr] + reconPic->m_buOffsetC[absPartIdx]; }

    /* lowres motion compensation, you must provide a buffer and stride for QPEL averaged pixels
     * in case QPEL is required.  Else it returns a pointer to the HPEL pixels */
    inline pixel *lowresMC(intptr_t blockOffset, const MV& qmv, pixel *buf, intptr_t& outstride)
    {
        if ((qmv.x | qmv.y) & 1)
        {
            int hpelA = (qmv.y & 2) | ((qmv.x & 2) >> 1);
            pixel *frefA = lowresPlane[hpelA] + blockOffset + (qmv.x >> 2) + (qmv.y >> 2) * lumaStride;
            int qmvx = qmv.x + (qmv.x & 1);
            int qmvy = qmv.y + (qmv.y & 1);
            int hpelB = (qmvy & 2) | ((qmvx & 2) >> 1);
            pixel *frefB = lowresPlane[hpelB] + blockOffset + (qmvx >> 2) + (qmvy >> 2) * lumaStride;
            primitives.pu[LUMA_8x8].pixelavg_pp(buf, outstride, frefA, lumaStride, frefB, lumaStride, 32);
            return buf;
        }
        else
        {
            outstride = lumaStride;
            int hpel = (qmv.y & 2) | ((qmv.x & 2) >> 1);
            return lowresPlane[hpel] + blockOffset + (qmv.x >> 2) + (qmv.y >> 2) * lumaStride;
        }
    }

    inline int lowresQPelCost(pixel *fenc, intptr_t blockOffset, const MV& qmv, pixelcmp_t comp)
    {
        if ((qmv.x | qmv.y) & 1)
        {
            ALIGN_VAR_16(pixel, subpelbuf[8 * 8]);
            int hpelA = (qmv.y & 2) | ((qmv.x & 2) >> 1);
            pixel *frefA = lowresPlane[hpelA] + blockOffset + (qmv.x >> 2) + (qmv.y >> 2) * lumaStride;
            int qmvx = qmv.x + (qmv.x & 1);
            int qmvy = qmv.y + (qmv.y & 1);
            int hpelB = (qmvy & 2) | ((qmvx & 2) >> 1);
            pixel *frefB = lowresPlane[hpelB] + blockOffset + (qmvx >> 2) + (qmvy >> 2) * lumaStride;
            primitives.pu[LUMA_8x8].pixelavg_pp(subpelbuf, 8, frefA, lumaStride, frefB, lumaStride, 32);
            return comp(fenc, FENC_STRIDE, subpelbuf, 8);
        }
        else
        {
            int hpel = (qmv.y & 2) | ((qmv.x & 2) >> 1);
            pixel *fref = lowresPlane[hpel] + blockOffset + (qmv.x >> 2) + (qmv.y >> 2) * lumaStride;
            return comp(fenc, FENC_STRIDE, fref, lumaStride);
        }
    }
};

/* lowres buffers, sizes and strides */
struct Lowres : public ReferencePlanes
{
    pixel *buffer[4];

    int    frameNum;         // Presentation frame number
    int    sliceType;        // Slice type decided by lookahead
    int    width;            // width of lowres frame in pixels
    int    lines;            // height of lowres frame in pixel lines
    int    leadingBframes;   // number of leading B frames for P or I

    bool   bScenecut;        // Set to false if the frame cannot possibly be part of a real scenecut.
    bool   bKeyframe;
    bool   bLastMiniGopBFrame;

    /* lookahead output data */
    int64_t   costEst[X265_BFRAME_MAX + 2][X265_BFRAME_MAX + 2];
    int64_t   costEstAq[X265_BFRAME_MAX + 2][X265_BFRAME_MAX + 2];
    int32_t*  rowSatds[X265_BFRAME_MAX + 2][X265_BFRAME_MAX + 2];
    int       intraMbs[X265_BFRAME_MAX + 2];
    int32_t*  intraCost;
    uint8_t*  intraMode;
    int64_t   satdCost;
    uint16_t* lowresCostForRc;
    uint16_t(*lowresCosts[X265_BFRAME_MAX + 2][X265_BFRAME_MAX + 2]);
    int32_t*  lowresMvCosts[2][X265_BFRAME_MAX + 1];
    MV*       lowresMvs[2][X265_BFRAME_MAX + 1];
    uint32_t  maxBlocksInRow;
    uint32_t  maxBlocksInCol;

    /* used for vbvLookahead */
    int       plannedType[X265_LOOKAHEAD_MAX + 1];
    int64_t   plannedSatd[X265_LOOKAHEAD_MAX + 1];
    int       indB;
    int       bframes;

    /* rate control / adaptive quant data */
    double*   qpAqOffset;      // AQ QP offset values for each 16x16 CU
    double*   qpCuTreeOffset;  // cuTree QP offset values for each 16x16 CU
    int*      invQscaleFactor; // qScale values for qp Aq Offsets
    uint32_t* blockVariance;
    uint64_t  wp_ssd[3];       // This is different than SSDY, this is sum(pixel^2) - sum(pixel)^2 for entire frame
    uint64_t  wp_sum[3];
    uint64_t  frameVariance;

    /* cutree intermediate data */
    uint16_t* propagateCost;
    double    weightedCostDelta[X265_BFRAME_MAX + 2];
    ReferencePlanes weightedRef[X265_BFRAME_MAX + 2];

    bool create(PicYuv *origPic, int _bframes, bool bAqEnabled);
    void destroy();
    void init(PicYuv *origPic, int poc);
};
}
```

Does anybody knows why?Any clue would be appreciated!Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's not this file that cause the problem,but another file...
There is another file 'sllice.h' use the forward declaration as:

```
#ifndef X265_SLICE_H
#define X265_SLICE_H


#include "common.h"


namespace X265_NS {
// private namespace


class Frame;
class PicList;
class PicYuv;
class MotionReference;


enum SliceType
{
    B_SLICE,
    P_SLICE,
    I_SLICE
};


struct RPS
{
    int  numberOfPictures;
    int  numberOfNegativePictures;
    int  numberOfPositivePictures;


    int  poc[MAX_NUM_REF_PICS];
    int  deltaPOC[MAX_NUM_REF_PICS];
    bool bUsed[MAX_NUM_REF_PICS];


    RPS()
        : numberOfPictures(0)
        , numberOfNegativePictures(0)
        , numberOfPositivePictures(0)
    {
        memset(deltaPOC, 0, sizeof(deltaPOC));
        memset(poc, 0, sizeof(poc));
        memset(bUsed, 0, sizeof(bUsed));
    }


    void sortDeltaPOC();
};


namespace Profile {
    enum Name
    {
        NONE = 0,
        MAIN = 1,
        MAIN10 = 2,
        MAINSTILLPICTURE = 3,
        MAINREXT = 4,
        HIGHTHROUGHPUTREXT = 5
    };
}


namespace Level {
    enum Tier
    {
        MAIN = 0,
        HIGH = 1,
    };


    enum Name
    {
        NONE = 0,
        LEVEL1 = 30,
        LEVEL2 = 60,
        LEVEL2_1 = 63,
        LEVEL3 = 90,
        LEVEL3_1 = 93,
        LEVEL4 = 120,
        LEVEL4_1 = 123,
        LEVEL5 = 150,
        LEVEL5_1 = 153,
        LEVEL5_2 = 156,
        LEVEL6 = 180,
        LEVEL6_1 = 183,
        LEVEL6_2 = 186,
        LEVEL8_5 = 255,
    };
}


struct ProfileTierLevel
{
    int      profileIdc;
    int      levelIdc;
    uint32_t minCrForLevel;
    uint32_t maxLumaSrForLevel;
    uint32_t bitDepthConstraint;
    int      chromaFormatConstraint;
    bool     tierFlag;
    bool     progressiveSourceFlag;
    bool     interlacedSourceFlag;
    bool     nonPackedConstraintFlag;
    bool     frameOnlyConstraintFlag;
    bool     profileCompatibilityFlag[32];
    bool     intraConstraintFlag;
    bool     onePictureOnlyConstraintFlag;
    bool     lowerBitRateConstraintFlag;
};


struct HRDInfo
{
    uint32_t bitRateScale;
    uint32_t cpbSizeScale;
    uint32_t initialCpbRemovalDelayLength;
    uint32_t cpbRemovalDelayLength;
    uint32_t dpbOutputDelayLength;
    uint32_t bitRateValue;
    uint32_t cpbSizeValue;
    bool     cbrFlag;


    HRDInfo()
        : bitRateScale(0)
        , cpbSizeScale(0)
        , initialCpbRemovalDelayLength(1)
        , cpbRemovalDelayLength(1)
        , dpbOutputDelayLength(1)
        , cbrFlag(false)
    {
    }
};


struct TimingInfo
{
    uint32_t numUnitsInTick;
    uint32_t timeScale;
};


struct VPS
{
    HRDInfo          hrdParameters;
    ProfileTierLevel ptl;
    uint32_t         maxTempSubLayers;
    uint32_t         numReorderPics;
    uint32_t         maxDecPicBuffering;
    uint32_t         maxLatencyIncrease;
};


struct Window
{
    int  leftOffset;
    int  rightOffset;
    int  topOffset;
    int  bottomOffset;
    bool bEnabled;


    Window()
    {
        bEnabled = false;
    }
};


struct VUI
{
    int        aspectRatioIdc;
    int        sarWidth;
    int        sarHeight;
    int        videoFormat;
    int        colourPrimaries;
    int        transferCharacteristics;
    int        matrixCoefficients;
    int        chromaSampleLocTypeTopField;
    int        chromaSampleLocTypeBottomField;


    bool       aspectRatioInfoPresentFlag;
    bool       overscanInfoPresentFlag;
    bool       overscanAppropriateFlag;
    bool       videoSignalTypePresentFlag;
    bool       videoFullRangeFlag;
    bool       colourDescriptionPresentFlag;
    bool       chromaLocInfoPresentFlag;
    bool       frameFieldInfoPresentFlag;
    bool       fieldSeqFlag;
    bool       hrdParametersPresentFlag;


    HRDInfo    hrdParameters;
    Window     defaultDisplayWindow;
    TimingInfo timingInfo;
};


struct SPS
{
    /* cached PicYuv offset arrays, shared by all instances of
     * PicYuv created by this encoder */
    intptr_t* cuOffsetY;
    intptr_t* cuOffsetC;
    intptr_t* buOffsetY;
    intptr_t* buOffsetC;


    int      chromaFormatIdc;        // use param
    uint32_t picWidthInLumaSamples;  // use param
    uint32_t picHeightInLumaSamples; // use param


    uint32_t numCuInWidth;
    uint32_t numCuInHeight;
    uint32_t numCUsInFrame;
    uint32_t numPartitions;
    uint32_t numPartInCUSize;


    int      log2MinCodingBlockSize;
    int      log2DiffMaxMinCodingBlockSize;


    uint32_t quadtreeTULog2MaxSize;
    uint32_t quadtreeTULog2MinSize;


    uint32_t quadtreeTUMaxDepthInter; // use param
    uint32_t quadtreeTUMaxDepthIntra; // use param


    uint32_t maxAMPDepth;


    uint32_t maxTempSubLayers;   // max number of Temporal Sub layers
    uint32_t maxDecPicBuffering; // these are dups of VPS values
    uint32_t maxLatencyIncrease;
    int      numReorderPics;


    bool     bUseSAO; // use param
    bool     bUseAMP; // use param
    bool     bUseStrongIntraSmoothing; // use param
    bool     bTemporalMVPEnabled;


    Window   conformanceWindow;
    VUI      vuiParameters;


    SPS()
    {
        memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));
    }


    ~SPS()
    {
        X265_FREE(cuOffsetY);
        X265_FREE(cuOffsetC);
        X265_FREE(buOffsetY);
        X265_FREE(buOffsetC);
    }
};


struct PPS
{
    uint32_t maxCuDQPDepth;


    int      chromaQpOffset[2];      // use param
    int      deblockingFilterBetaOffsetDiv2;
    int      deblockingFilterTcOffsetDiv2;


    bool     bUseWeightPred;         // use param
    bool     bUseWeightedBiPred;     // use param
    bool     bUseDQP;
    bool     bConstrainedIntraPred;  // use param


    bool     bTransquantBypassEnabled;  // Indicates presence of cu_transquant_bypass_flag in CUs.
    bool     bTransformSkipEnabled;     // use param
    bool     bEntropyCodingSyncEnabled; // use param
    bool     bSignHideEnabled;          // use param


    bool     bDeblockingFilterControlPresent;
    bool     bPicDisableDeblockingFilter;
};


struct WeightParam
{
    // Explicit weighted prediction parameters parsed in slice header,
    uint32_t log2WeightDenom;
    int      inputWeight;
    int      inputOffset;
    bool     bPresentFlag;


    /* makes a non-h265 weight (i.e. fix7), into an h265 weight */
    void setFromWeightAndOffset(int w, int o, int denom, bool bNormalize)
    {
        inputOffset = o;
        log2WeightDenom = denom;
        inputWeight = w;
        while (bNormalize && log2WeightDenom > 0 && (inputWeight > 127))
        {
            log2WeightDenom--;
            inputWeight >>= 1;
        }


        inputWeight = X265_MIN(inputWeight, 127);
    }
};


#define SET_WEIGHT(w, b, s, d, o) \
    { \
        (w).inputWeight = (s); \
        (w).log2WeightDenom = (d); \
        (w).inputOffset = (o); \
        (w).bPresentFlag = (b); \
    }


class Slice
{
public:


    const SPS*  m_sps;
    const PPS*  m_pps;
    Frame*      m_refFrameList[2][MAX_NUM_REF + 1];
    PicYuv*     m_refReconPicList[2][MAX_NUM_REF + 1];


    WeightParam m_weightPredTable[2][MAX_NUM_REF][3]; // 
[list][refIdx][0:Y, 1:U, 2:V]
    MotionReference (*m_mref)[MAX_NUM_REF + 1];
    RPS         m_rps;


    NalUnitType m_nalUnitType;
    SliceType   m_sliceType;
    int         m_sliceQp;
    int         m_poc;
    int         m_lastIDR;


    uint32_t    m_colRefIdx;       // never modified


    int         m_numRefIdx[2];
    int         m_refPOCList[2][MAX_NUM_REF + 1];


    uint32_t    m_maxNumMergeCand; // use param
    uint32_t    m_endCUAddr;


    bool        m_bCheckLDC;       // TODO: is this necessary?
    bool        m_sLFaseFlag;      // loop filter boundary flag
    bool        m_colFromL0Flag;   // collocated picture from List0 or List1 flag


    Slice()
    {
        m_lastIDR = 0;
        m_sLFaseFlag = true;
        m_numRefIdx[0] = m_numRefIdx[1] = 0;
        memset(m_refFrameList, 0, sizeof(m_refFrameList));
        memset(m_refReconPicList, 0, sizeof(m_refReconPicList));
        memset(m_refPOCList, 0, sizeof(m_refPOCList));
        disableWeights();
    }


    void disableWeights();


    void setRefPicList(PicList& picList);


    bool getRapPicFlag() const
    {
        return m_nalUnitType == NAL_UNIT_CODED_SLICE_IDR_W_RADL
            || m_nalUnitType == NAL_UNIT_CODED_SLICE_CRA;
    }


    bool getIdrPicFlag() const
    {
        return m_nalUnitType == NAL_UNIT_CODED_SLICE_IDR_W_RADL;
    }


    bool isIRAP() const   { return m_nalUnitType >= 16 && m_nalUnitType <= 23; }


    bool isIntra()  const { return m_sliceType == I_SLICE; }


    bool isInterB() const { return m_sliceType == B_SLICE; }


    bool isInterP() const { return m_sliceType == P_SLICE; }


    uint32_t realEndAddress(uint32_t endCUAddr) const;
};


}


#endif // ifndef X265_SLICE_H
```

If I change forward declaration to including corresponding header, there will be no error!